# Add text: case insensitive and cross-platform

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file in which I need to convert the lines. From

```
<id>ABC</id>
<guid isPermaLink="false">ABC</guid>
```

need to get the following:

```
<id>ABC123</id>
<guid isPermaLink="false">ABC123</guid>
```

i.e., add text before `</id>` or `</guid>`.

The problem is that I cannot make this *case insensitive* and *cross-platform*; for BSD and GNU. As far as I understand, `sed` and `awk` are not very suitable for this purpose because of the difference between the BSD and GNU versions.

At this point I'm kind of stumped and don't know how to do such a fairly simple operation. Maybe someone can suggest the best way to solve it? Maybe it is possible to do this using only the shell's functions?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

With `sub` function of `awk` you could try following. Though experts always advise to use tools like xmlstarlet which understand xml better.

```
awk '{sub(/<\/(gu)?id/,"123&")} 1' Input_file
```

OR in case you want to make code to use ignorecase to match capital/smal letters then try following.

```
awk '{sub(/<\/([gG][Uu])?[iI][Dd]/,"123&")} 1' Input_file
```

OR in case you have GNU `awk` in with you try with `IGNORECASE` option:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{sub(/<\/(gu)?id/,"123&")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sub`(substitution) function of `awk` to substitute `</guid>` OR `</id>` with `123</guid>` and `123</id>` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner (case-insensitive and cross-platform):

```
perl -lpe 's{(ABC)(</id>|</guid>)}{${1}123${2}}ig' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.
`/i` : Case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable ignore case substitution then consider `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's~(?i)</(?:gu)?ID>~123$&~' file

<id>ABC123</id>
<guid isPermaLink="false">ABC123</guid>
```